# How to Release golable instance variables in ARC mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have created multiple insances in my h file

> ```
> IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
> IBOutlet UIImageView *subImageView;
> ```

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *arrowRight;
IBOutlet UIImageView *arrowLeft;
IBOutlet UIImageView *arrowDown;
```

My project is in the ARC mode

do i have to set them to nil in dealloc () method inorder to release them??

Thanks

Comment: If you have global variables that are actually reset every lifetime of instances of a particular view controller, you may be entering a world of pain.

Comment: Are these global variables are instance variables? They can only be one or the other, and people seem confused as to which you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the global instances after one of your objects is deallocated, the best way would be to set the global pointers to `nil` in `dealloc`.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    gYourGlobalPointer = nil;
}
```

Note that in ARC you can't call `[super dealloc]`, dealloc will be sent to your superclass automatically.

Comment: you can add Flag or mention as a duplicate question Becouse its lots of answer same as hear

Answer (score 0):

you can make them nil in  `viewDidUnload` as following:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ARC you don't have to worry about releasing instance veritable of a property at all. Compiler will take care of them for you.

If you want to release manually you have to assign nil to all strong variables pointing to particular instance.